# getting application has stopped working for winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, command-line, crash, exe

Have a standalone application which will work without UI or with UI, based on the parameters passed from command line. Noticed some time "application has stopped working" error.

The ResourcePk.exe is compiled with X64 platform.

Noticed the below errors in the event logs.

In System-1:

```
Faulting application name: ResourcePk.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5f8e75ea
Faulting module name: System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll, version: 4.8.4261.0, time stamp: 0x5f4ff3fc
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0020d4cb
Faulting process id: 0x324
Faulting application start time: 0x01d6a8594b6720ea
Faulting application path: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2\IXP000.TMP\ResourcePk.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\54ee5c7acea4374219f1ed6bbf372ed1\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll
Report Id: 38a2a852-144d-11eb-80e0-005056816cfd
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

In System-2:

```
Faulting application name: ResourcePk.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5f88ec92
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.14393.3986, time stamp: 0x5f77edfa
Exception code: 0xc000041d
Fault offset: 0x000dc562
Faulting process id: 0xf40
Faulting application start time: 0x01d6a35d8293f715
Faulting application path: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\IXP000.TMP\ResourcePk.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 573df694-adf3-4aea-963a-1e08ed8919cd
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

[EDIT] Dumplogs:

```
ntdll_777d0000!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+c    
KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+cc    
kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjects+19    
kernel32!WerpReportFaultInternal+50b    
kernel32!WerpReportFault+74    
kernel32!BasepReportFault+19    
KERNELBASE!UnhandledExceptionFilter+1f4    
ntdll_777d0000!LdrpLogFatalUserCallbackException+4d    
ntdll_777d0000!KiUserCallbackExceptionHandler+26    
ntdll_777d0000!ExecuteHandler2+26    
ntdll_777d0000!ExecuteHandler+24    
ntdll_777d0000!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+f    
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+48    
clr!RaiseTheExceptionInternalOnly+230    
clr!IL_Throw+146    
System_Drawing_ni![COLD] System.Drawing.Graphics.ReleaseHdcInternal(IntPtr)$##60001F6+d    
System_Drawing_ni!System.Drawing.Graphics.ReleaseHdc()$##60001F5+e    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.WindowsGraphicsWrapper.Dispose()$##6004CA2+14    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.DrawText(System.Drawing.IDeviceContext, System.String, System.Drawing.Font, System.Drawing.Rectangle, System.Drawing.Color, System.Windows.Forms.TextFormatFlags)$##6004C95+f4    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripRenderer.OnRenderItemText(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemTextRenderEventArgs)$##6004372+c4    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripRenderer.DrawItemText(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemTextRenderEventArgs)$##6004358+16    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripLabel.PaintText(System.Drawing.Graphics)$##60040AD+103    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel.OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)$##6004468+e0    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandlePaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)$##6003F9D+2f    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(System.EventArgs, System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemEventType)$##6003F8C+33    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)$##6003BAC+3d4    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs, Int16)$##6000E5A+6d    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)$##6000F05+3eb    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)$##6000F0F+358    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)$##6003481+31    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)$##6003BE0+4c    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)$##6003717+34    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)$##600571D+13    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)$##6005720+35    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)$##6002DED+80    
0x0115d08e    
user32!_InternalCallWinProc+2b    
user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+262    
user32!DispatchClientMessage+dc    
user32!__fnDWORD+49    
ntdll_777d0000!KiUserCallbackDispatcher+36    
user32!DispatchMessageWorker+313    
user32!DispatchMessageW+10    
combase!CCliModalLoop::HandleWakeForMsg+155 [d:\blue\com\combase\dcomrem\callctrl.cxx @ 1733 + a]   d:\blue\com\combase\dcomrem\callctrl.cxx @ 1733 + a 
combase!CCliModalLoop::BlockFn+19d [d:\blue\com\combase\dcomrem\callctrl.cxx @ 1618 + 75873453]   d:\blue\com\combase\dcomrem\callctrl.cxx @ 1618 + 75873453 
combase!ClassicSTAThreadWaitForHandles+9e [d:\blue\com\combase\dcomrem\classicsta.cpp @ 46 + e]   d:\blue\com\combase\dcomrem\classicsta.cpp @ 46 + e 
combase!CoWaitForMultipleHandles+84 [d:\blue\com\combase\dcomrem\sync.cxx @ 120 + 10]   d:\blue\com\combase\dcomrem\sync.cxx @ 120 + 10 
clr!MsgWaitHelper+64    
clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+1d8    
clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+64    
clr!CLREventBase::WaitEx+121    
clr!CLREventBase::Wait+1a    
clr!WaitForEndOfShutdown_OneIteration+81    
clr!WaitForEndOfShutdown+1b    
clr!EEShutDown+ad    
clr!HandleExitProcessHelper+4d    
clr!EEPolicy::HandleExitProcess+50    
clr!ForceEEShutdown+31    
clr!SystemNative::Exit+4f    
mscorlib_ni!System.Environment.Exit(Int32)$##6000E34+43    
0x089db459    
mscorlib_ni!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(System.Object)$##6006FCB+1a    
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)$##6003AF0+c4    
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)$##6003AEF+17    
mscorlib_ni!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()$##6006FCA+5e    
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.InvokeAction(System.Object)$##6004065+2c    
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.Run(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)$##6004056+129    
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()$##6003FD3+47d    
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()$##6003FAA+1a    
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.__Canon].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)$##6003E85+54    
mscorlib_ni!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[System.__Canon].SetResult(System.__Canon)$##6005D0C+78    
0x089ddfc0    
mscorlib_ni!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(System.Object)$##6006FCB+1a    
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)$##6003AF0+c4    
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)$##6003AEF+17    
mscorlib_ni!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()$##6006FCA+5e    
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation+<>c.<.cctor>b__8_0(System.Object)$##6006ECA+2a    
clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+6b    
clr!CallDescrWorkerReflectionWrapper+55    
clr!RuntimeMethodHandle::InvokeMethod+838    
mscorlib_ni!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[])$##6004658+a9    
mscorlib_ni!System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(System.Object[])$##60006DB+7d    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry)$##6000DDD+b1    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(System.Object)$##6000DDC+68    
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)$##6003AF0+c4    
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)$##6003AEF+17    
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)$##6003AEE+44    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry)$##6000DDB+9e    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()$##6000DDE+e2    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)$##6000F0F+11f    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)$##600571D+13    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)$##6005720+35    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)$##6002DED+80    
0x0115d08e    
user32!_InternalCallWinProc+2b    
user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+18e    
user32!DispatchMessageWorker+208    
user32!DispatchMessageW+10    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(MSG ByRef)$##6000000+3d    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr, Int32, Int32)$##600550A+25f    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)$##6005539+175    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)$##6005538+4f    
System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form)$##60005FA+35    
0x02fa0d31    
clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+34    
clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+6b    
clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+16a    
clr!RunMain+19d    
clr!Assembly::ExecuteMainMethod+f7    
clr!SystemDomain::ExecuteMainMethod+5ef    
clr!ExecuteEXE+4c    
clr!_CorExeMainInternal+dc    
clr!_CorExeMain+4d    
mscoreei!_CorExeMain+d6    
mscoree!_CorExeMain_Exported+8c    
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+24    
ntdll_777d0000!__RtlUserThreadStart+2f    
ntdll_777d0000!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b
```

Comment: `C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32` seems to be a path to x86 dll. Are you sure, that you'll run app in x64 bit OS?  Does app correctly compiled to x64 target?

Comment: Yes we run against 64bit OS & it is compiled against x64. "AnyCPU" would resolve this problem?